# move from one point to another using three js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have created a sphere object and used world .jpg to create earth using webgl. 
below is the code:

```
var geometry   = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.5, 32, 32)
var material  = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial()
var earthMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
scene.add(earthMesh)
material.map    = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/earthmap1k.jpg')
```

I want to create a line geometry and add to the globe between latitudes and longitudes. I also want the animation of the lines on the globe.

I have tried to create line geometry and add it to the scene but it does not overlaying properly on the globe